# Сохранить на флешку образ установленной ОС Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ос

Подскажите, как сохранить на флешку образ установленной на ноутбук DELL ОС Ubuntu 16.04? В последующем планирую восстановление / установку ОС с флешки.

Купил ноутбук DELL с предустановленной системой ubuntu 16.04 для учебных целей, т.е. возможны существенные изменения. Но если возникнут ошибки в системе, хотел бы иметь возможность откатиться до версии, с которой был куплен ноутбук. 
Как вариант сохранить образ текущей ОС на флешку.
Возможно будут иные предложения...

---

Для ноутбука DELL с Ubuntu нашел инсталлированное решение: dell.com/support/article/ua/ru/uabsdt1/sln265750/…

Comment: Быть может так https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/backup
Первая ссылка в выдаче

Comment: Для клонирования линуксов очень хорошо идёт clonezilla, как и говорил @vscoder. Но конкретно в твоём случае - я бы забил, потому что воткнуть любой линукс на ноут - не сильно большая проблема, а магазинные оси не сделаны под тебя. Вообще смысла нет.

Answer (score 2):

Можно создать образ раздела или всего диска с помощью [clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/), сохранив его на внешний носитель.